# Join values by keys

Tags: normal-mode

I would like to use VIM to group a file by keys (e.g. "asian") and join the associated values. The keys are already sorted.

Example:

```
asian <==> asiat
asian <==> asiatisk
asiatic <==> asiat
asiatic <==> asiatisk
associate professor <==> docent
association member <==> föreningsmedlem
assyria <==> assyrien
assyrian <==> assyrier
assyrian <==> assyrisk
```

Expected output:

```
asian <==> asiat | asiatisk
asiatic <==> asiat | asiatisk
associate professor <==> docent
association member <==> föreningsmedlem
assyria <==> assyrien
assyrian <==> assyrier | assyrisk
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This is an interesting question to me because my first instinct would be to use other command-line tools (i.e., not vim)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a very convoluted way. In two steps

1. I build the dictionary

   ```
   let d = {}
   %s/^\(.\+\) <==> \(\S\+\)/\=string(extend(extend(d, {submatch(1): []}, 'keep')[submatch(1)], [submatch(2)]))
   ```

   NB: Vim has very few ways to return an expression that modifies the input parameter, `extend()` is one of them; and `:substitute` + `\=` and `submatch()` is a way to extract the two parts. `split()` may be a way to simplify things

   So, I use `extend()` twice. A first time to make sure the key exists in the dictionary. And a second time to add the last value to the key.

   and I clean

   ```
   %d_
   ```
2. I generate the new lines

   ```
   call setline(1, map(items(d), {k, v -> printf('%s <==> %s', v[0], join(v[1], ' | '))}))
   %sort
   ```